# npm dependency tangled web - my library requires a different version of a package than one of my dependencies uses

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

This has to be a common scenario but I'm not finding a clear answer. This has been dogging me for a few days now.

**Scenario**:

I built a private library/dependency and reference it in package.json in my main project:

```
"my-shared-lib": "git+https://myuser:mypass@github.com/mygh/my-shared-lib.git#dev"
```

However, one of the packages in my main project relies upon the same package (which is "[uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)"), but a different version. Not sure which, maybe it's React or something else. Due to a difference in that 3rd party dependency's file & folder structure, Webpack throws an error on build:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/my-github-lib/data/guid_id.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'uuid/v1' in
>   'C:\MyProject\node_modules\my-github-lib\data' resolve 'uuid/v1' in
>   'C:\MyProject\node_modules\my-github-lib\data'   Parsed request is a
>   module   using description file:
>   C:\MyProject\node_modules\my-github-lib\package.json (relative path:
>   ./data)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration   after using description file:
>   C:\MyProject\node_modules\my-github-lib\package.json (relative path:
>   ./data)
>       resolve as module
>         looking for modules in C:\MyProject
>           using description file: C:\MyProject\package.json (relative path: .)
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           after using description file: C:\MyProject\package.json (relative path: .)
>             using description file: C:\MyProject\package.json (relative path: ./uuid/v1)
>               no extension
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 C:\MyProject\uuid\v1 doesn't exist
>               *
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 C:\MyProject\uuid\v1* doesn't exist
>               .js
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 C:\MyProject\uuid\v1.js doesn't exist
>               .jsx
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 C:\MyProject\uuid\v1.jsx doesn't exist
>               as directory
>                 C:\MyProject\uuid\v1 doesn't exist
>         C:\MyProject\node_modules\my-github-lib\data\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\MyProject\node_modules\my-github-lib\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\MyProject\node_modules\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\MyProject\projects\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\MyProject\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Projects\MyProject\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Projects\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\Users\myuser\Documents\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\Users\myuser\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\Users\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         C:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
>         looking for modules in C:\MyProject\node_modules
>           using description file: C:\MyProject\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           after using description file: C:\MyProject\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
>             using description file: C:\MyProject\node_modules\uuid\package.json (relative path: ./v1)
>               no extension
>                 C:\MyProject\node_modules\uuid\v1 doesn't exist
>               *
>                 C:\MyProject\node_modules\uuid\v1* doesn't exist
>               .js
>                 C:\MyProject\node_modules\uuid\v1.js doesn't exist
>               .jsx
>                 C:\MyProject\node_modules\uuid\v1.jsx doesn't exist
>               as directory
>                 C:\MyProject\node_modules\uuid\v1 doesn't exist [C:\MyProject\uuid\v1] [C:\MyProject\uuid\v1*]
>   [C:\MyProject\uuid\v1.js] [C:\MyProject\uuid\v1.jsx]
>   [C:\MyProject\uuid\v1]
>   [C:\MyProject\node_modules\my-github-lib\data\node_modules]
>   [C:\MyProject\node_modules\my-github-lib\node_modules]
>   [C:\MyProject\node_modules\node_modules]
>   [C:\MyProject\projects\node_modules] [C:\MyProject\node_modules]
>   [C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Projects\MyProject\node_modules]
>   [C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Projects\node_modules]
>   [C:\Users\myuser\Documents\node_modules]
>   [C:\Users\myuser\node_modules] [C:\Users\node_modules]
>   [C:\node_modules] [C:\MyProject\node_modules\uuid\v1]
>   [C:\MyProject\node_modules\uuid\v1*]
>   [C:\MyProject\node_modules\uuid\v1.js]
>   [C:\MyProject\node_modules\uuid\v1.jsx]
>   [C:\MyProject\node_modules\uuid\v1]

This is just one example - it's happening to 6 other libraries and has the same error message.

I can confirm this conflict by looking at my library's copy:

[image]
[image]

...and what is installed in my main project:

[image]
[image]

Clearly I need both versions of this dependency to satisfy my build, but forcing either version breaks something.

What is the elegant solution to this?

Comment: I'm not able to re-create this by simply creating a new test library w/ the uuid package as a dependency, then referencing it from my main React app project. It just works. I can honestly say I have no idea what is causing this, at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Webpack bug that's was acknowledged in March, but has yet to be fixed.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447

The proposed workaround worked for me, which is adding a line like so, for each package listed in the build errors:

```
node: {
    fs: "empty",
    net: "empty",
    tls: "empty"
}
```

Not sure I like this workaround. If it happens to more dependencies, I'd lose the option of using these packages on the client-side, no?